# Select rows with latest timestamp using certain criteria and additional tables SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I was hoping someone could help me in resolving this issue.

I have 3 tables.

Every table has an ID that I can use to connect all of them together. Those ID's are not the same ones, but they work and connect to each other alright.

What I need to get is LATEST update date (timestamp) for certain product number (could be more than one product) what was status for it.

Here are how tables look like (they are much more complex, but i simplified them)

```
mercury.cs_batch_event
PRODUCT_ID (VARCHAR2(100 CHAR))
CBL_REQUEST_ID (VARCHAR2(12 CHAR))

mercury.cs_status_srch
CBL_REQUEST_ID (VARCHAR2(12 CHAR))
LOG_ID  (VARCHAR2(12 CHAR))
STATUS_REF_ID (NUMBER(8,0))

mercury.edit_log
ELOG_ID (VARCHAR2(12 CHAR))
ON_DATE_TIME (TIMESTAMP(6))
```

I tried doing it several different ways, and after searching for a while on the internet, closest i could get to was this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT cbl.product_id, src.status_ref_id,
             TO_CHAR(elog.on_date_time, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') date_updated
      FROM mercury.cs_batch_event cbl,
           mercury.cs_status_srch src, 
           mercury.edit_log elog
      WHERE cbl.product_id IN ('A555', 'B555')
        AND cbl.cbl_request_id = src.cbl_request_id
        AND src.log_id = elog.elog_id
      ORDER BY elog.on_date_time DESC)
WHERE rownum = 1
```

And it returned below which is correct, but when several product numbers are inserted it still returns value for only one product (Which is because of the `row number=1` probably)

```
PRODUCT_NUMBER  DATE_UPDATED        STATUS
A555            29/06/2011 07:51:24 30169
```

Thanks

Comment: Okay, can we get some sample _starting_ data for this?  The set of answers is potentially large, because you may have many-many relationships you haven't told us about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT 
  t1.product_number, 
  t2.status, 
  TO_CHAR (t3.update_time, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') date_updated,
FROM 
  batch_event t1, 
  status_srch t2, 
  edit_log t3
WHERE 
  t1.product_number in ('A555', 'B555')
  AND t1.ID_1 = t2.ID_1
  AND t2.ID_2 = t3.ID_2
  AND t3.update_time = (SELECT max(update_time) 
                        FROM edit_log 
                        WHERE ID_2 = t3.ID_2)
```

Ahh, think I misunderstood your data.. Try this instead:

```
SELECT 
  t1.product_number,
  t2.status,
  t3.update_time
FROM 
  batch_event t1, 
  status_srch t2, 
  edit_log t3,
(
    SELECT 
      batch_event.product_number product_number, 
      max(edit_log.update_time) maxupdatetime,
    FROM 
      batch_event, 
      status_srch, 
      edit_log
    WHERE 
      batch_event.ID_1 = status_srch.ID_1
      AND status_srch.ID_2 = edit_log.ID_2
    GROUP BY
      batch_event.product_number
) t4
WHERE t1.ID_1 = t2.ID_1
AND t2.ID_2 = t3.ID_2
AND t1.product_number = t4.product_number
AND t3.update_time = t4.maxupdatetime
```

Comment: Cheers fot tha will have a go with it now!

Comment: It didn't seem to work for me, as it gave me all Updated times fro that product.

Comment: I've updated my orignal tables and sql to what we actually have in database, as I was getting mixed up with them and it took me a while to rename it all!

Comment: Hey It looks like it is working, it deffinteley comes back with more product codes when I search by more than one product code. I will test it more tomorrow and see! Thanks for that!!!

Comment: Hey Stevie, above is working like I wanted it! Thank you very much for you help! much apprecieted!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Might be a good case for [analytic functions](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm)

```
SELECT product_id,
       status_ref_id,
       TO_CHAR(on_date_time, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
FROM (SELECT cbl.product_id,
             src.status_ref_id,
             elog.on_date_time,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cbl.product_id ORDER BY on_date_time DESC)
               AS ordered_by_recency
      FROM mercury.cs_batch_event cbl,
           mercury.cs_status_srch src, 
       mercury.edit_log elog
      WHERE cbl.product_id IN ('A555', 'B555')
        AND cbl.cbl_request_id = src.cbl_request_id
        AND src.log_id = elog.elog_id) d
WHERE ordered_by_recency = 1
```

Comment: Hey Pilcrow, thanks for your help, but I already got it working from Stevie's query!

Comment: @Greg, I'm glad.  Doesn't hurt to have more than on correct way to do it, either. :)

Comment: Absolutely I will still consider it, I'm just a bit pressured now by time to get whatever I need! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.product_number, t2.status,
    (SELECT Update_Time FROM Edit_log el
     INNER JOIN Status_srch ss ON el.ID_2 = ss.ID_2
     INNER JOIN Batch_event be ON ss.ID_1 = be.ID_1
     WHERE be.Product Number = t1.product_number
           AND RowNum<=1
     ORDER BY Update_Time DESC) AS date_updated
FROM Batch_event t1 
INNER JOIN Status_srch t2 ON t1.ID_1 = t2.ID_1
WHERE t1.product_number in ('A555', 'B555')
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I think I tried something like that with SELECT TOP 1 and it gave me an error!

Comment: Doesn't look like its working as I'm getting missing expression error.

Comment: @Greg: try my new code... I wrote (Product Code) instead of product_code. Try and let me know

Comment: Thanks Marco, It wasn't Product_code that was the problem, This is embarrasing but i'm don't think I'm using SQL server! This might be reason its not working!

Comment: @Greg: Are you using MySql? Postgres? Oracle? Try to guess and let me know. Which error do you get now?

Comment: I've updated my orignal tables and sql to what we actually have in database, as I was getting mixed up with them and it took me a while to rename it all!

Comment: @Greg: I didn't change fields names, but only where condition according to oracle syntax. Rename fields, try and let me know

Comment: I tried the new version and came back with error! ORA-00936: missing expression! After t2.status, in top line should there be a coma after it? It give me error with or witout it!

Comment: @Marco - At minimum, you have a mismatch in number of opening v. closing parenthesis.

Comment: Hey Marco, I've tried updated version and it still gives me an error, but it is ok as I got it working from another query! Thanks anyway fro all your help, much appreciated!